# PostgreSQL simple count query

Tags: postgresql

Trying to scale this down so the answer is simple. I can probably extrapolate the answers here to apply to a bigger data set.

Given the following table:

```
+------+-----+
| name | age |
+------+-----+
| a    |   5 |
| b    |   7 |
| c    |   8 |
| d    |   8 |
| e    |  10 |
+------+-----+
```

I want to make a table that shows the count of people where their age is equal to or greater than x. For instance, the table about would produce:

```
+--------------+-------+
| at least age | count |
+--------------+-------+
|            5 |     5 |
|            6 |     4 |
|            7 |     4 |
|            8 |     3 |
|            9 |     1 |
|           10 |     1 |
+--------------+-------+
```

Is there a single query that can accomplish this task? Obviously, it is easy to write a simple function for it, but I'm hoping to be able to do this quickly with one query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you're looking for is a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS).

```
with cte_age_count as (
  select   age,
           count(*) c_star
    from   people
  group by age)
select age,
       sum(c_star) over (order by age
                         range between unbounded preceding
                                   and current row)
  from cte_age_count
```

Not syntax checked ... let me know if it works!